# How to start threading the function and stop threading by the buttons with Tasks

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm doing winforms app that can automatically run the Wooting-Double-Movement when Fortnite is running, but I need to thread the function. I can't thread it by System.Threading.Tasks. I tried to use Thread.Start and Thread.Abort but Thread.Abort doesn't work in .NET Core 5.0. So, how can I do this?
Button4 is start button and Button5 is stop

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AutoDoubleMovement
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        static Settings Settings = new Settings();
        static Info Info = new Info();

        static string path = $@"C:\Users\{Environment.UserName}\AppData\Local\AutoWDM";
        static string file = $@"{path}\WDM_path.txt";
        static string file_wdm = File.ReadAllText(file);

        // Threading this function
        public static void WDM()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string wdm_path = File.ReadAllText(file);
                Process[] fortnite = Process.GetProcessesByName("FortniteClient-Win64-Shipping");
                Process[] wdm = Process.GetProcessesByName("wooting-double-movement");
                ProcessStartInfo wdmproc = new ProcessStartInfo() { FileName = wdm_path };

                foreach (Process _wdm in wdm)
                {
                    if (fortnite.Length != 0)
                    {
                        if (wdm.Length == 0)
                        {
                            Process.Start(wdmproc);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (wdm.Length != 0)
                        {
                            _wdm.Kill();
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Settings.Owner = this;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    if (Directory.Exists(path))
                    {
                        File.WriteAllText(file, ofd.FileName);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    File.WriteAllText(file, ofd.FileName);
                }
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Settings.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Info.ShowDialog();
        }

        // This is the button to start threading WDM
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!textBox1.Text.Contains("wooting-double-movement.exe"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your path doesn't contain \"wooting-double-movement.exe\" file", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                button1.Enabled = false;
                button4.Enabled = false;
                button5.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        // This is the button to stop threading WDM
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button4.Enabled = false;
            button5.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (File.Exists(file))
            {
                textBox1.Text = file_wdm; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if you didn't understand something, sorry for that, I'm not American

Comment: What does *I can't thread it by System.Threading.Tasks* mean? You cannot use `Task.Run()` passing a CancellationToken? Why?

Comment: @Jimi I don't know how to do this. I tried many of examples but I can't make it work

Comment: Well, post your best shot at it, so it can be fixed.

Comment: You have `while (true)` and `Thread.Sleep(1000);` within. This could be solved by simply adding a TIMER to your Form and setting the Interval to 1000. There are lots of other ways to "fix" your problem, though. Hint, change the `true` in your while loop to a variable that can be toggled so the loop can drop out?...

Answer (score 0):

1. DO NOT USE static OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog(); Make dialogs only with using () { }
2. Try not Task but normal Thread, with .Start() and .Abort()

Comment: As I said, Thread.Abort is not working in .NET Core 5.0